# PhoneGap : How to call a Java class function from the phonegap iOS plugin

Tags: java, cordova, ios7, phonegap-plugins

I am a learner in PhoneGap.
My requirement is once my objective C method in native code i.e in PhoneGap iOS plugin, I need to call a Java class functions in the objective C . Is that possible to call a  Java class function. Please let me know how this can be achieved.